# change membership class time zone

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-membership

I noticed recently that when I create new users using the `Membership Class` all of the time fields like `LastActivityDate` are saved as `UTC` (4hrs ahead of my time zone). I thought there might be a value to change in the `web.config` to use my time zone but there isn't, [this is all that is available.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.membershipprovider_properties)

Is there a way to change which time zone is used by the membership class or is this one of those things that CANNOT be changed because it is standard practice to use `UTC`

Answer (score 3):

The LastActivityDate is saved on UTC, but when you read it is converted to the LocalTime of the server. This is the code when you call to view it.

```
public virtual DateTime LastActivityDate
{
    get
    {
        return this._LastActivityDate.ToLocalTime();
    }
}
```